# How to view all records with rating 1, 3 and 5 Laravel query

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to filter by rating. It can be for a record from 1 to 5. From the frontend comes a string, for example "1,3,5", which means - show all entries with a rating of 1, 3 and 5 at once.

```
$reviews = $this->data['sort_by'] = Review::query()
                ->where('rating', $data['rating'])
                ->get()
```

This is how I can get with only one value, but I need several at once. Also, the difficulty is that there can be not only "1, 3, 5", but also any other combinations, for example, "1, 4, 3" or "3,5,2"

If someone means how to compose a request before the get () method, it would be ideal so that all the work is at the database level and the server does not have to filter the collection, but in any case, I will be very happy with any solution where there will be only one request to the database data. Of course, I can make a separate request for each rating and glue them later, but that would be bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

explode the posted rating so it becomes an array and use `whereIn()` instead of `where()`:

```
$reviews = $this->data['sort_by'] = Review::query()
                    ->whereIn('rating', explode(',', $data['rating']))
                    ->get()
```